# delete previous frame objects and mute one audio file per object in a Array AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, drag-and-drop, flash-cs6

Well I am doing a little game app of drag and drop to a target. I have 4 objects named on the dropArray, 4 targets named on the hitArray, and 4 audio files that correspond to the objects array named on the soundArray.

The 4 audio files should start syncronized (at the same time) but with the volume turned down, so when an object hits the target it turns up a volume of the corresponding audio file.

The objects are snapping to the targets correctly. I figured out how to start all the audio files at the same time (maybe it is not the best way).

The goal of the app is that the 4 audio files correspond to each instrument of the song. When you drop let say "dragJuan" to "dragJuan_t" the "voz.mp3" must starts to sound. The audio files are Vocal, guitar, bass and drum. So when the 4 audio files play together a song is completed and this should happen when the 4 object are in their target.

This app is on one frame of the Flash CS6 file. I have a total od 8 frames with different pages of the presentation and only the second frame contains this app.

**PROBLEMS:**

1) When an object hits the target all the audio files are turned up and turned down when it is out of its target . And I just need that each object turns up its correponding audio file, and when it is out of its target the volume turns down again.

2) When I click on a button to go to whatever frame I want, lets say the 4th frame of the project, the dropArray object that has been clicked remains on the stage dragging and dropping as it where on the its frame. I tried to put a `removeChild(dragJuan);` at the first of the next frame and it works but only with the first dropArray object I put, if I put the 4 object (each one with a removeChild();) it only works with the first object and the other 3 don't.

Thank you for any help or advice you could give me! I am new on ActionScript and this is for a  homework and don't figure it out how to make it work!

Cheers,
Monojorge

```
SoundMixer.stopAll();
stop();

import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
import flash.events.Event;

var hitArray:Array = new Array(dragJuan_t,dragBeto_t,dragFil_t,dragMono_t);
var dropArray:Array = new Array(dragJuan,dragBeto,dragFil,dragMono);
var soundArray:Array = new Array("voz.mp3","bateria.mp3","bajo.mp3","guitarra.mp3");
var positionsArray:Array = new Array();
var songController:SoundChannel;
var sTransform:SoundTransform;

var audioFile:URLRequest=new URLRequest(soundArray[0]);
var audioFile2:URLRequest=new URLRequest(soundArray[1]);
var audioFile3:URLRequest=new URLRequest(soundArray[2]);
var audioFile4:URLRequest=new URLRequest(soundArray[3]);

var song:Sound = new Sound();
var song2:Sound = new Sound();
var song3:Sound = new Sound();
var song4:Sound = new Sound();

song.load(audioFile);
song2.load(audioFile2);
song3.load(audioFile3);
song4.load(audioFile4);

songController = song.play(0, 9999);
songController = song2.play(0, 9999);
songController = song3.play(0, 9999);
songController = song4.play(0, 9999);

trace (soundArray);

SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);

//This adds the mouse down and up listener to the drop instances
//and add the starting x and y positions of the drop instances
//into the array.

for (var i:int = 0; i < dropArray.length; i++)
{
        dropArray[i].buttonMode = true;
        dropArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mdown);
        dropArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);

        positionsArray.push({xPos:dropArray[i].x, yPos:dropArray[i].y});
}



//This drags the object that has been selected and moves it;
//to the top of the display list. This means you can't drag
//this object underneath anything.

function mdown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
        e.currentTarget.startDrag();
        setChildIndex(MovieClip(e.currentTarget), numChildren - 1);
}

//This stops the dragging of the selected object when the mouse is
//released. If the object is dropped on the corresponding target
//then it get set to the x and y position of the target. Otherwise
//it returns to the original position.
function mUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{

        var dropIndex:int = dropArray.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
        var target:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

        target.stopDrag();

        if (target.hitTestObject(hitArray[dropIndex]))
        {
                target.x = hitArray[dropIndex].x;
                target.y = hitArray[dropIndex].y;
                square_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_RotateContinuously);

                SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
                // This is turning up the volume of all audio files and I just need to turn up the volume of the audio that corresponding to the object array.

                trace(target);

        }
        else
        {
                target.x = positionsArray[dropIndex].xPos;
                target.y = positionsArray[dropIndex].yPos;

                SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
                // This is turning down the volume of all audio files and I just need to turn down the volume of the audio that corresponding to the object array.

        }


}


function fl_RotateContinuously(event:Event)
        {
                square_mc.rotation +=  10;
                if (square_mc.rotation == 180)
                {
                        square_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_RotateContinuously);
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed the problem that I had with the remaining object. I just take all the objects and converted them to a movie clip and that's it. I still have problems with tbe audio part!